# get_declared_classes() only returning classes I am directly using

Tags: php

I am trying to get a list of classes that implement an interface of mine. Those classes are dynamically instantiated based on user input.

```
public function new($className) {
    $instance = new $className;
    return $instance;
}

public function getClasses() {
    var_dump(get_declared_classes());
}
```

However, when I am using `get_declared_classes()`, those implementations of the interface are not in the list. If I instantiate them manually and throw them away, they will appear in the list.

Giraffe will appear below, but not in the example above.

```
public function new($className) {
    $throwAway = new Giraffe();
    $instance = new $className;
    return $instance;
}

public function getClasses() {
    var_dump(get_declared_classes());
}
```

How do I get a list including those implementations, without having to instantiate each of them like above?

Comment: You never need such a things. Better use interfaces. Be SOLID ;)

Comment: I need to know which classes implements the interface, in the example above it could be `AnimalInterface`, to build a dropdown in the GUI. The end user will then pick which `AnimalInterface` implementation should eat his apple.

Comment: You dont to need the classes. Send the interface as an object. (Dependency inversion)

Comment: How do you propose getting a hold of the object? The client will send a string with the name of the implementation it wants to use, e.g. `Giraffe`